# Can't fix error of Array Index Out of Bounds

Tags: java

The code that the error is pointing to is:

```
letters[addr(tmp.charAt(0))] = Integer.parseInt(tmp.substring(2,tmp.length()))
```

And it is initialized in main:

```
int letters[] = new int[26]; //holds variables
for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
    letters[i] = i+1;
    }
```

The error says that the string Index is out of bounds: -1. I am pretty sure that it is not the control that is doing this, as when i commented out control it did the same thing. I am trying to figure out how to fix this, and would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Share some sample data for "tmp"

Comment: `String tmp = scanner.next();`

Comment: what is the length of your string tmp?

Comment: If `tmp.length()` is `1`, `substring()` will throw a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` with message `String index out of range: -1`.

Comment: Yeah my length is 1. How would you recommend fixing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just place an if condition before as follows

```
String tmp = scanner.next();

if(!tmp.length()<=1)
{
letters[addr(tmp.charAt(0))] = Integer.parseInt(tmp.substring(2,tmp.length()))\
}

else
{
    //do something to handle ArrayOutOfBondsException
}
```

Comment: Actually, check for tmp.length() >= 3, since substring(2, tmp.length()) starts at the 3rd character of tmp.